# Basic CSS layout issue, white space at bottom

Tags: html, css, layout

Sorry for the silly question but for some reason this part of HTML/CSS layout always gets me...

I have a website at http://kdmalikdesign.com/test/LinguisticPeers/index.html.  Just practicing HTML/CSS/jQuery and eventually PHP/Databases.

In chrome the footer ends up being way too long.  In firefox the footer is about three times what I want it and in safari the same.  Right now i have height 100% on the html and body so that the background image expands to everything that is showing.

To compensate for the footer (now being too long) will I have to make the main container a minimum length so the footer will accomodate the space?  Is there a general design rule over this? or CSS rule?

Basically what is happening is I like the way the header and main container look but since it doesn't fill the whole browser window it ends up making the footer wayyyy too long OR if html,body 100% isn't there, there becomes a white space below the footer.  My CSS code is below if you want to quickly check it.

The only heights are 100% on the html,body.  The Header has a height of 100px and each container is 160px.  The footer is also 55px.

```
html, body, div, header, footer, article, h2 {
    margin: 0px;
    padding: 0px;
}

html, body {
    height: 100%;
    background-image: url('images/bkg-img.jpg');
    background-repeat: repeat;
}
header {
background: #6888fd; /* Old browsers */
background: -moz-linear-gradient(top, #6888fd 0%, #1c46e9 55%, #0330e4 100%); /* FF3.6+ */
background: -webkit-gradient(linear, left top, left bottom, color-stop(0%,#6888fd), color-stop(55%,#1c46e9), color-stop(100%,#0330e4)); /* Chrome,Safari4+ */
background: -webkit-linear-gradient(top, #6888fd 0%,#1c46e9 55%,#0330e4 100%); /* Chrome10+,Safari5.1+ */
background: -o-linear-gradient(top, #6888fd 0%,#1c46e9 55%,#0330e4 100%); /* Opera 11.10+ */
background: -ms-linear-gradient(top, #6888fd 0%,#1c46e9 55%,#0330e4 100%); /* IE10+ */
background: linear-gradient(to bottom, #6888fd 0%,#1c46e9 55%,#0330e4 100%); /* W3C */
filter: progid:DXImageTransform.Microsoft.gradient( startColorstr='#6888fd', endColorstr='#0330e4',GradientType=0 ); /* IE6-9 */
height: 100px;
}

#background-container {
    padding-top: 50px;
    padding-bottom: 25px;
}

#container {
    margin: 0 auto;
    background-color: #587DFF;
    height: 230px;
    width: 830px;

    text-align: center;
    padding-top: 100px;

    -moz-border-radius: 25px;
    border-radius: 25px;
}

#article-container {
    width: 960px;
    margin: 0 auto;
}

article {
    border: 4px solid #9AADFA;
    background-color: #002DE2;
    color: #fff;
    width: 280px;
    height: 160px;

    float: left;
    margin-left: 30px;
    margin-top: 25px;
    /* 
            display:-moz-inline-stack;
display:inline-block;
zoom:1;
*display:inline;
    */
}

.clear {
    clear: both;
}

span {
    display: block;
    padding-top: 10px;
    color: #6D8EFF;
}

h2 {
    padding-left: 10px;
    padding-top: 5px;
}

p {
    padding-left: 5px;
    padding-right: 5px;
}

footer {
    text-align: center;
    border-top: 1px solid #7493FF;
    background-image: url('images/bkg-img.jpg');
    background-repeat: repeat;

    height: 55px;
}

nav {
    float: right;
    color: #84A0FF;
    position: relative;
    top: 60px;
    left: -75px;
}

nav ul {
    list-style-type: none;
}

nav ul li {
    display: inline;
    padding-left: 10px;
}

#login-container {
    float: right;
    padding-right: 50px;
    padding-top: 25px;
    color: #fff;
    position: relative;
    left: 450px;
}

#header-container {
margin: 0 auto;
    width: 960px;
    height: 100px;
}
```

Comment: Can you post some screen of how you expect it looks like?

Comment: For me, I usually try adding a little more white space where I can, to change the page's height. For example, add a little more space between the three blue boxes and the line. Besides that, if you're going to have a lot of content in the main blue box that may fill up the space.

Comment: http://kdmalikdesign.com/test/LinguisticPeers/LinguisticPeersHomePage.gif that is what i'm going for Mateusz Rogulski.  I'm trying to avoid adding space between the boxes and the line or between the three boxes and the above big box, although I'm assuming that may be the way "it needs to be".  Also Lrdwhyt I will look at the sticky footer idea.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want the footer to stick to the bottom of the page, something like [this](http://ryanfait.com/sticky-footer/) might be helpful.

Comment: The sticky footer seems to do what I need although now there is just a large space under the boxes, but I think that will have to be a change in my layout somehow to make it look better. If anyone has any other ideas let me know though!